# ErrorException Non-static method should not be called statically - When Try to Fetch Data from Two Different Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to fetch data from different table.

I have 2 tables:

1. teacher_profiles
2. user_types

[image: teacher_profiles]

[image: user_types]

UserTypes model:

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TeacherProfile'); 
}
```

TeacherProfile model:

```
public function usertype()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserTypes'); 
}
```

Controller:

```
$usertype = TeacherProfile::usertype()->with('teacher');
return view('teachers.create')->with($usertype);
```

View:

```
@if ($usertype)
  @foreach($usertype as $data)
    <input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder=""  value="$data->id" required autofocus>
 @endforeach
@endif
```

then I encounter with ErrorException
Non-static method App\TeacherProfile::usertype() should not be called statically error

What I'm trying to do is to display 'teacher' with value '2' in the user type as picture below:

[image]

Comment: Complementing the answer of ersoy, you might want to check the way you're defining your relationships. The base of those relationships should be your User model. An user can have roles (usertype) and an user that's a teacher can have extra information (teacherProfile).

Comment: Relationships cannot be called statically like that, then need to be called inside a `with()` (or `has()`, `whereHas()`, etc) function. The answer below doesn't really explain that, but is still correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add get(), first() to the end of expression. That may do the trick.

```
$usertype = TeacherProfile::with('usertype.teacher')->get();
```